# Repetir una función varias veces en react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

necesito ayuda con algo estoy intentando hacer que se repita una función varias veces pero no lo realiza no se si estoy usando mal el for o si para realizar esta repetición en react hooks se realice de otra manera.

En mi codigo el product trae un arreglo y count es el numero de veces que quiero que se repita esa función de addToCart.

```
 const handleAddToCart = (product,count) => () =>
  {
    for (var i=0; i < count; i++ ){
      addToCart(product);
    }
       
  };
```

y aqui esta la funcion de addToCart

```
  const addToCart = (payload) => {
  
    
    setState({
      ...state,
      cart: [...state.cart,payload ],
    });
 
  };
```

Comment: Cuál es el error? Desde dónde estas llamando a handleAddToCart? Además dices que product es un arreglo, eso quiere decir que estas tratando de agregarle arreglos a un arreglo?

Comment: El error es que el for no repite las veces que quiero, quiero que  la función  se realice varias veces pero no lo realiza , por eso no se si tenga que hacer de otra manera ese for en react hooks

Comment: Por lo que veo, estas tratando de precargar productos a un carrito de compras al momento que se levanta el componente no?

Comment: si exactamente , entonces el producto es un arreglo y el otro es la cantidad de veces que quiero que ese producto se ponga en el carrito es decir que al arreglo le agrego dos veces o las veces que me mande en ese count

Comment: Ok, entiendo.. estas seguro que producto es un arreglo y no un objeto que se debe agregar?

Comment: si perdón es un objeto que quiero agregar al carrito varias veces con la funcion addTo Cart

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar a utilizar el hook **[effect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)** que ofrece `React`, con el cual puedes manejar la *visualización/actualización* de estados en el momento que requieras hacerlo.

Para este caso, sólo necesitamos que al momento que el componente se monta, se pre-cargue de datos el carro, por lo que necesitaríamos algo así

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    for (let x = 0; x <= count; x++) {
      addToCart(x);
    }
  }, []);
```

Con el segundo parámetro (`[]`), le estamos indicando que sólo debe ejecutarse una sola vez.

**[Acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-payne-dlzmy?file=/src/App.js)** el ejemplo completo para que lo revises.

Nos comentas que tal te va :D